# сокеты java проблемы с передачей данных

Tags: java, json

Здравствуйте. Пишу клиент-серверную игру на сокетах. На сервере создаются и постоянно изменяются несколько списков с обьектами (Пули, враги, etc), для передачи на клиент этих списков использую json(jackson). Проблема в производительности этого всего (при рисовании на клиенте очень глючит). На локальном уровне все работает нормально.  Помогите пожалуйста с оптимизацией, хотя бы в какую сторону двигаться.

**Класс передачи с сервера на клиент:**

```
 public class ClientConnection extends Thread {

  Socket client;
  OutputStream daos;
  PrintWriter printWriter;
  BufferedReader fromClient;
  GamePlay gamePlay;
  JsonGenerator jsonGenerator;
public ClientConnection(Socket client)
{
    gamePlay = new GamePlay(); //здесь обрабатывается игровая ситуация
    this.client = client;
    try {

        printWriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
        fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
        jsonGenerator = jsonFactory.createGenerator(daos);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    this.start();

}

@Override
public void run()
{
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_TARGET, false);

        while (true) {
            try {
                synchronized (gamePlay.bullets.getBullets()) {
                    mapper.writeValue(printWriter, gamePlay.bullets.getBullets());
                }
                synchronized (gamePlay.enemies.getEnemies()) {
                    mapper.writeValue(printWriter, gamePlay.enemies.getEnemies());
                }
                mapper.writeValue(printWriter,gamePlay.ship);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
}
```

**Класс считывания на клиенте**

```
public class Client extends Thread{

private static final String SERVER_IP    = "127.0.0.1";
private static final int    SERVER_PORT  = 9999;
DrawGame drawGame;
PrintWriter writer;
BufferedReader br;
JsonParser jsonParser;

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Socket clientSocket;
    PrintStream outToServer = null;
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();

    try {
        clientSocket = new Socket(Client.SERVER_IP,Client.SERVER_PORT);
        Client client = new Client();
        //client.inputStream = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        client.br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        client.writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        client.drawGame = new DrawGame(); //тут все рисуется
        client.jsonParser = jsonFactory.createParser(client.br);
        client.start();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.add(client.drawGame);




    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

@Override
public void run(){
    TypeReference bul = new TypeReference<ArrayList<Bullet>>() { };
    TypeReference enem = new TypeReference<ArrayList<Enemy>>() { };
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_TARGET, false);



    while (true) {
            try {

                ArrayList<Bullet> b = mapper.readValue(jsonParser,bul);
                drawGame.setBullets(b);
                ArrayList<Enemy> e = mapper.readValue(jsonParser,enem);
                drawGame.setEnemies(e);
                Ship ship = mapper.readValue(jsonParser, Ship.class);
                drawGame.ship = ship;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
        }


}
```

}

Comment: Прогоните это все дело в каком нибудь профайлере, том же VisualVM, будет видно где больше всего времени тратится, будет проще понять куда копать.

Comment: интересная программа, пригодится в арсенале. В принципе как я и думал проблема кроется в самой передачи данных, затратная функция сериализации/записи на сервере:                                         mapper.writeValue(printWriter, gamePlay.bullets.getBullets());                 
 и чуть менее, но все же, десериализации/чтения на клиенте.                                  ArrayList<Bullet> b = mapper.readValue(jsonParser,bul);   Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Json явно плохая затея для игр с сетевым обменом (клиент-сервер) пробуйте отправлять массив данных в байтах, конкретными пакетами, к примеру class Packet { public void write() { writeInt(2); writeString("Win"); } } и соответственно обрабатывайте в буфере данные. Поставьте себе netty в связке с протобафом как еще один вариант реализации общения акторов

Comment: Я думал на такой вариант, но откровенно говоря не совсем могу понять как его реализовать. Допустим у меня три объекта списки которых я отправляю в байтах, как мне на клиенте понять где какой объект? И для этого классы этих объектов должны существовать на обоих сторонах? Может мне что то подчитать нужно?)

Comment: Я так понял, его идея в том, что опознавать, что это за объект, мы будем по первому байту. writeInt(2); writeString("Win"); - из примера автора "2" я так понимаю это оно и есть, только если заменить это константой, например END_GAME_STATE. Но по сути это своя реализация сериализации. Но прежде чем перейти к сериализации, попробуйте поработать с сетью. Возможно вам стоит разделить сериализацию и собственно отправку данных. Потому что если данные дробятся на кучу пакетов, это будет тормозить очень сильно. Возможно получится отправить все данные из цикла одним пакетом TCP.

Comment: И еще, если для вашей игры не критична потеря данных одно-двух циклов - можно перейти на протокол UDP. Он точно будет быстрее, за счет отсутсвия механизмов гарантии доставки. Но вот насколько, я сходу не скажу, не тестировал.